# Control+G inside terminal is not functioning correctly

Tags: pantheon-terminal

While inside the terminal I cannot press Ctrl+G. This is painful inside Emacs as it is the keybinding for cancelling a command. I believe it is bound to something else inside the terminal. How do I disable that or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem as an emacs user.

Ctrl-G does work but it's assigned to something else. I checked the source code (https://github.com/elementary/terminal/blob/master/src/PantheonTerminalWindow.vala) and it turns out that Ctrl-G is used for `ACTION_SEARCH_NEXT` You can see this behaviour if you click the little magnifying glass button in terminal's title bar and enter a search term. Pressing ctrl-g will jump to the next hit of the search term.

As a quick and dirty fix, my plan is to disable the `ACTION_SEARCH_NEXT` keybinding (maybe just comment it out) and recompile locally. Though I believe a bug should be filed. In my opinion, ctrl-g should only be mapped to `ACTION_SEARCH_NEXT` when the search bar is active. By the way, this keybinding is used in other built apps such as Code and Epiphany.

Another work-around for now would be to install another terminal emulator. eg: xterm.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I have created a issue for it. https://github.com/elementary/terminal/issues/306

Comment: The fix has merged to master. I don't know when it will be pushed out as an update though.